# In Android, how can I get the content of the current tab?

Tags: android, loops, android-framelayout, tabwidget

I have a TabWidget that holds a set of ImageViews. The FrameLayout the TabWidget uses to display content is inside a HorizontalScrollView so multiple ImageViews can be seen via scroll.

[image]

I need to interact with the items within the tab content. More specifically, I have an array of elements. I need to get the children of the innermost FrameLayout and cycle through them to compare their tag to the the elements in my array. If there is a match I need to change their background. Looping through the children and changing the background, I know how to do. I'm just having issues getting to the ImageViews so I can cycle through them.

to note: I'm working with a layout I've inherited and I don't really have time to "redo" anything unless I really **have to**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your first `ImageView` would have the id: `firstimage`, try with:

```
TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) th.getCurrentView().findViewById(R.id.firstimage);
```

Comment: I _was_ using `getTabContentView()`. I switched it to `getCurrentView()` based on your answer. Now it's telling me the number of children and now I can cycle through them: `ViewGroup tabContent = (ViewGroup) tabHost.getCurrentView();`

Comment: Good to know, I've done a hard work in an app based on the same structure you posted, but in my case every tab had just one view as child (a `TextView`), so I tried to extrapolate it to your problem, at least now I know how to work based in many views too :-)

Comment: Yeah, now that I can get children I can just do a for loop based on `tabContent.getChildCount() -> tabContent.getChildAt[x]`